# Waterproofing concrete from the ground?

Tags: concrete, waterproofing

We want to build a table with benches outside.

For this, we have a concrete base with vertical rebars (40cm out of the ground).

We want to build brick columns for the structure of the table/bench (50/80 cm high).

Inside the brick columns, we would pour concrete (so it would hold the rebars, bricks together).

**The question:**

- Do we need to completely separate the concrete base from the brick columns/concrete in the columns?
- OR: we just need to put bituminous plates under the bricks and not the concrete in the center of the brick columns?

Image is from Google, but related:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how waterproofing plays into this question.  What about water concerns you?

Comment: Have you been looking at exterior brick walls with a "damp-proof course" and think that you need something similar?

Comment: I would pour it in place with nothing in between.

Comment: my concern is that water might damage the bricks. so the bricks are outside, which sometimes could get below 0 C.